# Pulse Audio plays 2% slower

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio

I have a problem with PulseAudio on my Buildroot based Raspberry Pi. It's playing audio 2% slower than normal. Indeed, after measurement, I get 100 BPM on the Raspberry when I have 102 on my computer, and it scales with the BPM. I always have `RPi's BPM = 98% normal BPM` .

It also works with frequencies, that are 2% smaller ...

I'm using a Raspberry Compute Module (CM1) with a Wolfson WM8731 audio codec.

I tried everything I found on the internet to play files in real time, have the best scheduling priority, but still that problem. It's very strange because I don't hear the music cracking or whatever. I also don't hear 'vibrato' effect because of frequency changing regularly. So it really seems that Pulse Audio is just 2% late compared to real time.

Do you guys have an idea of what could be the problem ?

Comment: Some timer is not correctly calibrated somewhere? Does it also happen is you stop Pulseaudio, and use ALSA directly?